# List filenames and folder paths on csv using batch file

Tags: batch-file, csv

I have a batch file that lists the full file directories (including filename at the end) onto a csv file. I need it to produce this, but also just the filename in a separate column. I would like it so that the format is Filename in first column (including extension) and full file directory in second column. The batch file I currently have is:

```
dir C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test\Files\*.tif /b /s >>
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test\Output.csv
```

EDIT: I forgot to mention the 'Files' folder contains many subfolders so I need it to process all files from all these subfolders.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to do this:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "in=C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test\Files\*.tif"
set "out=C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test\Output.csv"

if not exist "%out%" type nul>"%out%"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b/s %in%') do (
    >>%out% echo "%%~nxa","%%a"
)
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work, just gave me a blank csv. Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: sorry, I left my own test paths in. I've corrected it for yours.

Comment: In the line with the echo command: the `"%%a"` can be `"%%~dpa"` if you only want to path of the file as the second column.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate and write (`help for` for info on the `%~` variable modifiers):

```
@echo off
cd C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test\Files
for %%f in (*.tif) do echo "%%~nxf","%%~dpf" >> Output.csv
```

Comment: this is going to output his csv into the files dir. He wants it in test. A small change is needed.